# Can Trigger notifications to "immediately" be done programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I work on projects that manage triggers programmatically I would like to be able to set the notifications to "immediately" when I'm creating the triggers because **it's a real advantage to debugging** to get trigger errors fairly quickly via email.

Something like this would be great:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('StartDaily').timeBased().atHour(7).everyDays(1).notifications("immediately").create();
```

> I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests such a capability.  Does this capability exist?

Answer (score 1):

Oops. I just did an issues check and there's an [active issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/36755104) pretty close to this.